# How Do I Enumerate Boot Entries without Crashing My Program in C?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am trying to enumerate boot entries using the undocumented function "NtEnumerateBootEntries".

I am using [this webpage](https://www.codewarrior.cn/ntdoc/winxp/ex/NtEnumerateBootEntries.htm) as a reference.

My code:

```c
ULONG BufferLength;
NTSTATUS NtStatus = NtEnumerateBootEntries(NULL, &BufferLength);
if (NtStatus != STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL) { NtStatusErrorExit("NtEnumerateBootEntries", NtStatus); }

PBOOT_ENTRY_LIST* BootEntries = malloc(BufferLength);
NtStatus = NtEnumerateBootEntries(BootEntries, &BufferLength);
if (NT_ERROR(NtStatus)) { NtStatusErrorExit("NtEnumerateBootEntries", NtStatus); }

int NumBootEntries = sizeof(BootEntries) / sizeof(PBOOT_ENTRY_LIST*);
printf("Number of Boot Entries: %i\r\n", NumBootEntries);

for (int i = 0; i < NumBootEntries; i++) {
    BOOT_ENTRY BootEntry = BootEntries[i]->BootEntry;
    printf("Boot Entry ID: %lu\r\n", BootEntry.Id);
}
```

When I compile and run my code, my program prints the number of boot entries and then crashes. It does not print the boot entry ID.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `sizeof(BootEntries)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of your allocation

Comment: Use of *any* function that is not part of your program, and whose semantics are not defined by the C standard, gives your program undefined behavior. I doubt that's what you meant; please be more specific about what happens instead of the program working correctly.

Comment: @zwol The problem was not caused by the use of an undocumented function. 
My code checked to make sure `GetProcAddress` did not return NULL. 

I was incorrectly getting the number of boot entries, but that was not causing the undefined behavior, I believe.

I was getting undefined behavior because my buffer receiving the boot entries was incorrect. It was an array of pointers to a structure instead of an array of structures.

Comment: I didn't say "undocumented", I said "not defined by the C standard." Point being that if you're gonna throw the term "undefined behavior" around you're setting yourself up for some pedant like me to come along and point out that *none of the NTDLL APIs* are defined by the C standard and therefore the program could do anything whatsoever, there's no use trying to debug it.

Comment: Point being *don't use that term*. It's a garbage term. The C standard should be rewritten to avoid it. *Tell us what actually happened instead of the program working as expected,* and don't leave out any details.

Comment: @zwol Now I see what you mean. I was using vague terminology. I should have been more specific than simply "undefined behavior".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing two things wrong:

- I was doing `sizeof(BufferEntries)` instead of `BufferSize`
- I was doing `PBOOT_ENTRY_LIST*` instead of `BOOT_ENTRY_LIST*`

Working code:

```c
ULONG BufferLength;
NTSTATUS NtStatus = NtEnumerateBootEntries(NULL, &BufferLength);

BOOT_ENTRY_LIST* BootEntries = malloc(BufferLength);
NtStatus = NtEnumerateBootEntries(BootEntries, &BufferLength);

int NumBootEntries = BufferLength / sizeof(BOOT_ENTRY_LIST);

for (int i = 0; i < NumBootEntries; i++) {
    BOOT_ENTRY BootEntry = BootEntries[i].BootEntry;
    printf("Boot Entry ID: %lu\r\n", BootEntry.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely DON'T want "sizeof()".

I believe this should work (untested):

```
// Query buffer size
ULONG BufferLength;
NTSTATUS NtStatus = NtEnumerateBootEntries(NULL, &BufferLength);
if (NtStatus != STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL) { 
    NtStatusErrorExit("NtEnumerateBootEntries", NtStatus);
}

// Allocate buffer and query boot list
PBOOT_ENTRY_LIST* BootEntries = malloc(BufferLength);
if (BootEntries == NULL) { 
    // Flag malloc() error
} else {
    NtStatus = NtEnumerateBootEntries(BootEntries, &BufferLength);
    if (NT_ERROR(NtStatus)) {
        NtStatusErrorExit("NtEnumerateBootEntries", NtStatus);
    }
}

// Get #/Entries
// int NumBootEntries = sizeof(BootEntries) / sizeof(PBOOT_ENTRY_LIST*);  // <-- Don't do this...
UNIT Count;
NtStatus = pNtQueryBootEntryOrder(NULL, &Count);
PBOOT_ENTRY* BootEntries = new PBOOT_ENTRY[Count];
printf("Number of Boot Entries: %i\r\n", Count);

// Iterate list
UINT Length = 0;
for (UINT i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
    BootEntries[i] = (PBOOT_ENTRY) (Buffer + Length + 4);
    printf("Boot Entry ID: %lu\r\n", BootEntries[i].Id);
    Length += *(PULONG) (Buffer + Length);
}
```

Comment: I understand the main point of your code. It will get the data from NtEnumerateBootEntries, get the number of entries via NtQueryBootEntryOrder, and then iterate through the buffer with the count. Your code will not work, however, because of redefinition errors (BootEntries), referencing an undeclared variable (Buffer), and other things.  If your code was revised to fix these errors, it would be inefficient because the way to get the count would be through `Count / sizeof(ULONG)`, meaning a whole new function will have to be imported and called.

Comment: Also, after I posted my question and received feedback for finding the number of entries, I realized that the buffer receiving the data from NtEnumerateBootEntries must be `BOOT_ENTRY_LIST*` instead of `PBOOT_ENTRY_LIST*`. My code for getting the number of entries was incorrect, which could make your code helpful, but I found a solution that did not include NtQueryBootEntryOrder.